# FactoryGirl has many trait creation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, factory-bot, traits

I'm trying to get FactoryGirl to create quiz_question. But it's only creating the belongs to factory(quiz_campaign) in the test DB environment, not the has many factory(quiz_question).

quiz_campaign.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  trait :with_quiz_questions do
    after_create do |campaign|
      FactoryGirl.create(:quiz_question, quiz_campaign: campaign)
    end      
  end
end

factory :quiz_campaign do 
   subdomain "macy"
end
```

quiz_question.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :quiz_question do
    message "What's your question"
  end
end
```

quiz_home_page.feature

```
Given(/^there's a subdomain for a quiz campaign$/) do
  @quiz_campaign = create(:quiz_campaign)
end

When(/^I visit the quiz campaign microsite subdomain url$/) do
  visit_with_subdomain microsite_home_path, subdomain: @quiz_campaign.subdomain
end
```

Comment: There is no relationship between your error and FactoryGirl creating a record

Comment: And the information you are providing is very disjointed

Comment: But anyways, what is the content of your route.rb?

Comment: is that all you have in your route.rb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by not using traits. It seems like using traits causes more complex solution than needed